# Bigquery select non duplicate records

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following table (simplified version):

```
id int,
amount decimal,
transaction_no,
location_id int,
created_at datetime
```

The above schema is used to store POS receipts for restaurants. Now, this table sometimes contains a receipt from same date, same ***transaction_no*** at same ***location_id***.

In which case what I want to do is get the last receipt of that ***location_id*** & ***transaction_no*** order by ***created_at desc***.

In MySQL, I use the following query which gets me last (`max(created_at)` receipt for a ***location_id*** & ***transaction_no***:

```
SELECT id, amount, transaction_no, location_id, created_at
 FROM receipts r JOIN
 (SELECT transaction_no, max(created_at) AS maxca
  FROM receipts r
  GROUP BY transaction_no
 ) t
 ON r.transaction_no = t.transaction_no AND r.created_at = t.maxca
group by location_id;
```

But when I run the same in BigQuery, I get the following error:

> **Query Failed Error**: Shuffle reached broadcast limit for table __I0
>   (broadcasted at least 150393576 bytes). Consider using partitioned
>   joins instead of broadcast joins . Job ID:
>   circular-gist-812:job_A_CfsSKJICuRs07j7LHVbkqcpSg

Any idea how to make the above query work in BigQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, amount, transaction_no, location_id, created_at 
FROM (
  SELECT 
  id, amount, transaction_no, location_id, created_at, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_no, location_id 
                    ORDER BY created_at DESC) as last
  FROM your_dataset.your_table
)
WHERE last = 1
```

Comment: This gives me flattened output. is there a way which I can keep the nested structure? I already unchecked Flatten results option in [bigquery web ui](https://www.evernote.com/l/ACRfvDG5ERpJPLBZ9ooZpOOIb_WKFvhEs6wB/image.png)